# How to replace values in column in one DataFrame by values from second DataFrame both have major key in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have 2 DataFrames in Python Pandas like below:

DF1

```
COL1 | ...  | COLn
-----|------|-------
A    | ...  | ...
B    | ...  | ...
A    | ...  | ...
.... | ...  | ...
```

DF2

```
G1  | G2
----|-----
A   | 1
B   | 2
C   | 3
D   | 4
```

And I need to replace values from `DF1 COL1` by values from `DF2 G2`

So, as a result I need DF1 in formt like below:

```
COL1 | ...  | COLn
-----|------|-------
1    | ...  | ...
2    | ...  | ...
1    | ...  | ...
.... | ...  | ...
```

Of course my table in huge and it could be good to do that automaticly not by manually adjusting the values :)

How can I do that in Python Pandas?

Comment: can't you just add a new column and drop the one you don't need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"COL1": ["A", "B", "A"]}) # Add more columns as required
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"G1": ["A", "B", "C", "D"], "G2": [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df1["COL1"] = df1["COL1"].map(df2.set_index("G1")["G2"])
```

output df1:

```
   COL1
0     1
1     2
2     1
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the assign or update method of Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 'B': [4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': [7, 8, 9]})
```

try

```
df1 = df1.assign(B=df2['B'])# assign will create a new Dataframe
```

or

```
df1.update(df2)# update makes a in place modification
```

here are links to the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html